# Automatic acknowledgement indicating Group Policy Object was applied

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, group-policy, windows-xp

Is there any way to automatically get an acknowledgment on the Domain Controller, as soon as a Group Policy Object (example: ABC) is applied to a PC on the domain?

**Server OS:** Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition (Domain Controller)

**Client OS:** Windows XP or Windows 7 (Desktops and Laptops)

Using the Domain Controller, can I track how many PCs (Windows XP and Windows 7), a particular Group Policy Object is applied to?

I.e. As soon as one Group Policy has been applied, then, the PC must send an acknowledgement to the Domain controller that this policy has been applied.

We have approximately 500 desktops and laptops. Laptops may sometimes not be connected to the LAN.

Is there any way to accomplish this task using any software?

Answer (score 1):

Im not aware of a mechanism, but if its only for a small numberof gpo's you could add a script to the gpo that would write a text file to a share.  The share could be \gpoupdate$\gponame .  The file name could be %computername%-%date%-%time% .

Answer (score 0):

Group Policy Management > Group Policy Results> "Policy Events"

It gives you information if a policy was successfully applied, and you can also take "advanced view" and see what GPO settings are applied.

Another option:

Enable Group Policy events on the client, create a script which reads these audit logs and then report back the results to a server/file share.